# SQL Timestamp query: Check if one timestamp is earlier than another

Tags: sql, oracle, date, timestamp, window-functions

For CallLogTable....I need to write a query which finds scenarios where the **created_ts** timestamp of one row has an earlier timestamp than the **updated_ts** timestamp of the row immediately BEFORE. Rows 1 and 2 are an example (The created_ts of row 2 is earlier than the updated_ts of row 1). I have seen use of Rownums but not sure how to apply it here. Many thanks in advance for your help!

[image: CallLogTable]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use window functions. `lag()` lets you access the previous row, and you can then compare the relevant columns:

```
select *
from (
    select  
        t.*,
        lag(updated_ts) over(order by id) lag_updated_ts
    from mytable t
) t
where created_ts < lag_updated_ts
```

This assumes that column `id` can be used to order the records. If you want a different column for ordering, then you can change the `order by` clause of the window function.

Comment: Is there a way (in SQL Server) that I can ignore the milliseconds difference?

i.e Only return scenarios where there is a difference of seconds

Comment: Is there a way I can rule out the milliseconds in this query?? Many many thanks. 
(Or more ideally state a time difference of say, 5 seconds)